# How to calculate the scale factor of non-linear ADC output value?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, adc, power-electronics, math

I am not good in maths. I am trying to find a scale factor (or closest) of the output of an ADC without success.

I prefer to don't use a table to calculate the value.

My ADC gives a value that is not correct (maybe for another hardware topic) but very close to it.

How do I get a factor number in order to multiply it and get a good value?

The scale is not linear but the 0.019mV is always the same between 1 to 2, 2 to 3, etc.

This is my situation:

[image]

Comment: there is no clue to nonlinearity. I would assume that you have to add the offset wich you found and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: I know that I can create an offset table but I prefer to avoid it if possible..

Answer (score 1):

So you have a scale and zero error.

V = 1.019*ADC_READING + .047mV, based on the points above.

Chances are the best gain factor is somewhat different from 1.019- to get an accurate factor, pick points that are widely separated within the linear range of the ADC.

Eg. If the ADC has a linear range that includes 1mV and 100mV you could calculate:

Scale factor k = \$\frac{\Delta V_{IN}}{\Delta \text {ADC_READING}}\$ = \$\frac{\text {99mV}}{\Delta \text {ADC_READING}}\$ for inputs of 100mV and 1mV.

Which is the same as what I did above, but because of the larger change in Vin the scale factor will be more accurate.

Then you can calculate the offset b to minimize the error on some basis. You might choose to minimize it at 1mV since it is a larger percentage of reading at low input values.

So b = 1mV - k*ADC_READING  (with input = 1 mV)

And V = k*ADC_READING + b

Comment: ohh what a good idea.. something like that known function: map(float x, float oMin, float oMax, float nMin, float nMax )

Comment: map(float x, float oMin, float oMax, float nMin, float nMax ) Worked like a charm! thank you all